# How to use SetWindowLong in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I use this function:

```
[DllImport ( "user32.dll" )]
static extern int SetWindowLong ( IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong );
```

and pass values from these:

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/Window%20styles.html

```
enum WindowLongFlags : int
{
    GWL_EXSTYLE = -20,
    GWLP_HINSTANCE = -6,
    GWLP_HWNDPARENT = -8,
    GWL_ID = -12,
    GWL_STYLE = -16,
    GWL_USERDATA = -21,
    GWL_WNDPROC = -4,
    DWLP_USER = 0x8,
    DWLP_MSGRESULT = 0x0,
    DWLP_DLGPROC = 0x4
}
```

So when I call it as:

```
SetWindowLong ( c, WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE, WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPED );
```

I get these errors:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'timoti.WindowLongFlags' to 'int'
>
> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'timoti.WindowStyles' to 'uint'

Is the pinvoke signature wrong as I have seen different ones online or am I missing something else?

Comment: Change your pinvoke signature to be the enum types. They should marshal correctly.

Comment: Or change the method signature to use `uint` instead of `int` for the index.

Comment: Thanks Peter I did that but it still shows can't convert from int to uint for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should fix it

```
SetWindowLong ( c, (int)WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE,
    (uint) WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPED);
```